# Cancel anonymous TimerTask

Tags: java, multithreading

```
boolean timing = true; /* this is a global attribute and its only here for context */
Timer t = new Timer();
t.schedule(new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Platform.runLater(() -> {
                new Thread(() -> {
                    if (!timing) {
                        try {
                            tt.cancel(); /* I want to cancel this if timming is false*/
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    } else {
                        update();
                    }
                }).run();
            });
        }
}, 10, 10);
```

I want to know if is possible to cancel that particular TimerTask inside of itself, please note that "tt" is only an example, I didn't know what else to call it. thanks.

Comment: What is the point of `new Thread(...).run()`?

Comment: Also, are you looking for something like `TimerTask.this` that works in anonymous classes?

Comment: This is a Javafx application and I want to use this thread to update a label on my layout

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Timer`s have their own background threads. Unless your tasks take a very long time to run, you do not need to create a new thread within the `#run()` method of the task (and you should not).

You can cancel subsequent executions of the timer by making the instance `final`:

```
final Timer t = new Timer();
t.schedule(new TimerTask() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // Do work.
        if (!timing) {
            t.cancel();
        }
    }
});
```

(Exception handling omitted for brevity.)

If you only want to cancel the task itself (allowing other tasks scheduled by the timer to continue running), it's a trivial call to the [#cancel()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TimerTask.html#cancel%28%29) method of the task instance:

```
if (!timing) {
    this.cancel();
}
```

You should also ensure that your `timing` variable is declared `volatile`. If you don't, the value could be cached in each thread, and you won't be able to observe changes.

Answer (score 0):

How about you make a new method to cancel the `Timer`?

```
private void cancelTimer(Timer t)
{
    t.cancel();
}
```

You also need to make the `Timer` final.